# How can I click on link containing a particular span in behat

Tags: html, testing, automation, behat, mink

Please help with the code to click on `text` by referring to `text1` in Behat.

`text1` is a unique property name and I have to use this to click on link `text`.

```
<h3>
<span class="label label-default">text1</span>
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success btn-style" href="link1">
<span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
text
</a>
```

Comment: This is for behat 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277333/mink-goutte-how-to-check-checkbox-without-attribute-in-goutte  If you have behat 3 then you should have something similar,  a find in your object and click after. You should click on the link using css like a[href*=link1]

Answer (score 1):

On your method (step method) Using a MinkContext object or directly in your FeatureContext:

```
$cssSelector = //the css value you want to click
$this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css'. $cssSelector)->click();
```

You can find your exactly cssselector value in chrome console in "Elements" tab, by clicking in your mouse right button -> Copy -> Copy Selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'css' selector here to click 'text'. If the class = icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus, then try the code below:

$this->getSession->getPage()->find('css','.icon .glyphicon .glyphicon-plus)->click();

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try:

```
ElementInterface::findAll
```

Then loop for each node and compare both, the tag and the value with your key.

Good look.