# Behat change result status when add javascript annotation

Tags: php, selenium, behat

I want to use behat to example test and I used Mink and Selenium to test javascript. I have a a element  in html file and when I click on the link then JQuery add to DOM new element.  I want to test this case.

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "^3.1",
        "bossa/phpspec2-expect": "^1.0",
        "behat/mink-extension": "^2.2",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3",
        "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "^1.3",
        "behat/mink": "^1.7"
    }
}
```

behat.yml

```
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      goutte:  ~
      browser_name: firefox
      selenium2: 
       wd_host: http://0.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
```

example.feature

```
Feature: example

  Scenario: Test javascript for
    Given I am on "http://www.example.com/"
    When I follow "clickButton" #a has id clickButton
    Then  I should see "Works!"
```

Behat throw error in Then  I should see "Works!" step  and it is fine, because this element not exists on body.

But when add @javascript annotation

```
@javascript
Feature: example
  Scenario: Test javascript for
    Given I am on "http://www.example.com/"
    When I follow "clickButton"
    Then  I should see "Works!"
```

Behat throw exception:

> When I follow "clickButton" # FeatureContext::clickLink()
>         Link with id|title|alt|text "clickButton" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)

What's wrong? I have Selenium on server.

Comment: Have you tried using a wait to see what happens?

Comment: Behat break command. Throw exception, that's all. I  don't know, why.

Comment: If you have jQuery then you coul create a step like 'wait for the page to be loaded' that should wait until all requests are done using wait() and a js/jQ condition

Comment: Ok, fine. When I create this step : 

   ` /**
     * @Then /^I wait for the suggestion box to appear$/
     */
    public function iWaitForTheSuggestionBoxToAppear()
    {
        $this->getSession()->wait(5000);
    }` 

It's works but I wonder , when I remove @javascript annotation this step "When I follow "clickButton" work fine,  but I add @javascript annotation this step not work..

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200240/behat-selenium-2-wait-for-page-to-load  and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277333/mink-goutte-how-to-check-checkbox-without-attribute-in-goutte